# Svelte with VSCode - how do you manage esbuild platform error?

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm learning Svelte and in my very first project I'm seeing this unexpected error in VSCode with the (official) 'Svelte for VS Code' extension.

[Photo of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddh84.png)

> You installed esbuild for another platform than the one you're currently using.
> This won't work because esbuild is written with native code and needs to
> install a platform-specific binary executable.
>
> Specifically the "@esbuild/linux-x64" package is present but this platform
> needs the "@esbuild/win32-x64" package instead. People often get into this
> situation by installing esbuild on Windows or macOS and copying "node_modules"
> into a Docker image that runs Linux, or by copying "node_modules" between
> Windows and WSL environments.
>
> If you are installing with npm, you can try not copying the "node_modules"
> directory when you copy the files over, and running "npm ci" or "npm install"
> on the destination platform after the copy. Or you could consider using yarn
> instead of npm which has built-in support for installing a package on multiple
> platforms simultaneously.
>
> If you are installing with yarn, you can try listing both this platform and the
> other platform in your ".yarnrc.yml" file using the "supportedArchitectures"
> feature: https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc/#supportedArchitectures
> Keep in mind that this means multiple copies of esbuild will be present.
>
> Another alternative is to use the "esbuild-wasm" package instead, which works
> the same way on all platforms. But it comes with a heavy performance cost and
> can sometimes be 10x slower than the "esbuild" package, so you may also not
> want to do that.

I set up a brand new project with vite as follows:

`npm init vite` - select Svelte, Typescript

`npm install`

Then navigate to any *.svelte file in the project and when the Svelte extension parser kicks in the error appears.

I assume this error is because I build and run the project through the WSL terminal, and npm uses the linux package when configured this way. VSCode in my windows environment is complaining seemingly because it expects the windows version of the package, even though I am developing in Linux through WSL?

I'm curious if there is any way to surpress the error here in VSCode. Using `yarn create vite` instead to setup the project still results in the same error, and I would prefer to use npm. Alternatively, is there another way I should be using the terminal in a Windows environment? I had thought that using WSL in this manner was pretty common.

Comment: Can you try installing 'esbuild' on its own in the same directory first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to answer my own question after some research.

The error was present because I was using a windows workspace in VSCode, while running all of my commands in a WSL terminal. This doesn't work with VSCode extensions because it expects you are working in a windows environment, and the extensions are configured as such.

You can use a WSL workspace in VSCode with the bash command `code .` to open VSCode in the current working directory. This also sets the workspace in VSCode to WSL, which allows the plugins to work correctly.